# 2.2 REST API change order STATE

Tags: rest-api

Is it possible to change the order state via the REST API?

My issue at the moment is that I have orders stuck in the Payment Review state and I can not Invoice/Cancel/Ship them via the back end or the API.

I feel like I need to get the state of the order back to processing to be able to do any of these things but I can not find any way to move an order out of the Payment Review state either with the back end or the API.

As such these orders do not correctly track to customers or update stock information.

Comment: yes this is possible. what have you tried to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POST {{baseUrl}}/V1/orders/

```
{
    "entity": {
        "entity_id":<entity_id>,
        "state":<state>,
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my god! thanks! I was trying a very similar method and having zero luck... this worked perfectly

Comment: please upvote and accept if it helped.

Comment: Done, sadly stack wont accept my upvote yet (<15 rep)